# Golang converting string to individual json values and not a list, similar to json.loads in python

Tags: json, string, go, marshalling

Apologies for this noob question.

I am trying to convert a string to json. The string is already in json format like

```
{ "system1": "Service 1", "System2": "Service2" }
```

or

```
{ "system1": "Service 1", "device": "Service 10", "Something": "port 22" }
```

and so on. The number of this key-value pair is not known at compile time, and is known only at the runtime.

I am able to load it to a struct, with predefined fixed keynames, but since the number of keys are varying, I am stuck at generating a json with respect to the structure of the string.

I am not looking for pushing it to a `string : []map[string]string` and my aim is to generate individually generate the key-value pair similar to python's `json.loads` on the string (Not prefering `string : []map[string]string` because to get an element out of it, I have to iterate over it, which takes `O(n)` time, but since the keys are known in runtime, and not a list, I could directly call it as `if value.Key`. Please correct me if I am wrong.)

The way I could do it with python was,

```
>>> a =  { "system1": "Service 1", "System2": "Service2" } 
>>> b = json.loads(a)
>>> b
{u'system1': u'Service 1', u'System2': u'Service2'}
```

and I could access elements as

```
b['system1']
```

without iterating over b, because it is not a slice.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott.

Comment: Unmarshal to `map[string]string` and you are done.

Comment: That was easy. Thank you @Volker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unmarshal the string in a map[string]interface{}.
For example https://play.golang.org/p/fjgg0iQgV1